# radar attenuation calculations

Tags: radar, attenuation

I would like to ask a few questions that are probably not difficult for engineers to figure out. Personally, I am not an engineer but want to learn about radars. I am having trouble understanding the equation in a book by Merrill Skolnik. The text says the attenuation factor is \$e^{-2\alpha R_{max}}\$

Based on the pictures and what you know:

- Is it saying in the text that \$-2\alpha R\$ is equal to \$-4.34\alpha R\$  or am I misunderstanding?
- Is the e in the equation the number that is about 2.718?
- How can R<sub>max</sub> be both left and right of the = sign? Am I supposed to calculate R<sub>max</sub> and then redo the equation with the attenuation factor?

I would really appreciate some assistance on this.

[image: radar range equation]

[image: description of attenuation factor and converting to nepers/distance]

Comment: coax cables have similar behavior.

Answer (score 3):

I wonder exactly why you care about the radar range equation, given you aren't an engineer. I'd love to hear about that.

If you read the text you will see ***exp*** used. The *exp* function is the value \$e\$ (as you point out, a number close to 2.718) raised to the given power. For example, \$e^x=\operatorname{exp}\left(x\right)\$. So, yes, in the equation that is what \$e\$ is.

In your radar range example, the idea they are talking about isn't complicated.

Imagine the radar emits rays that proceed outward and are partially absorbed as they pass through the air. We can imagine that a certain percentage remains after traveling some given distance. When it travels further along for the same distance, there will be a percentage of the original percentage. And so on.

This is a multiplicative process (repeated multiplication.) Such processes are easily represented by using power equations (like \$a^b\$.) The above description can be turned into a mathematical expression. Let's say that the remaining percentage of a ray, after traveling a certain distance, is called \$\gamma\$ (we can call it anything.) Then after twice this distance we'd have \$\gamma^2\$ left over. And after three times the distance we'd have \$\gamma^3\$ remaining.

Assuming that \$R\$ is the distance (specified in those certain units), then we can say that what remains of each ray is \$\propto \gamma^R\$ (reads: *proportional to* \$\gamma^R\$.) However, since your equation deals with both the outgoing and return paths where the transmitter and receiver are at the same location, the total path length is twice the maximum range. So this means \$\propto \gamma^{2\cdot R}\$ (to account for the total path being twice the maximum range.)

This can be transformed:

$$\begin{align*}
\propto &\quad \gamma^{2\cdot R}\\\\
&\quad e^{\operatorname{ln}\left(\gamma^{2\cdot R}\right)}\\\\
&\quad e^{2\cdot R\:\operatorname{ln}\gamma}
\end{align*}$$

Since \$\gamma\$ is less than 1, \$\operatorname{ln}\gamma\$ is negative. If we treat \$\alpha=-\operatorname{ln}\gamma\$ (so that \$\alpha\$ is positive [or zero]) then the resulting factor is \$\propto\:e^{-2\cdot \alpha\cdot R}\$.

Since decibels for power are based on \$10\cdot\operatorname{log_{10}}\left(x\right)\$ (and not the attenuation factor, directly), you can re-express the prior ratio in decibels as:

$$\begin{align*}
&{10\cdot\operatorname{log_{10}}\left(e^{-2\cdot \alpha\cdot R}\right)}\\\\
&{-2\cdot \alpha\cdot R\cdot 10\cdot\operatorname{log_{10}}\left(e\right)}\\\\
&{-2\cdot \alpha\cdot R\cdot 4.34294482}\\\\
&{-2\cdot \left(4.34294482\cdot \alpha\right)\cdot R}
\end{align*}$$

Finally, yes. You do need to solve for \$R_\text{MAX}\$ and to do that you will need the LambertW (product-log) function. It's not at all hard to apply here. If you need help with it, I can walk you through the few lines of algebraic manipulation (it's not much work at all.)

---

Let's lump all the factors into a single constant, \$k_0\$, such that:

$$R_\text{MAX}^4=k_0\cdot e^{-2\,\alpha\, R_\text{MAX}}$$

(I'm sure you can see what \$k_0\$ is without forcing me to write out all those factors in the photocopied equation you have in your question.)

Then just follow the steps below:

$$\begin{align*}
R_\text{MAX}^4&=k_0\cdot e^{-2\,\alpha\, R_\text{MAX}}\\\\
\sqrt[\leftroot{0}\uproot{2}4]{R_\text{MAX}^4}&=\sqrt[\leftroot{0}\uproot{2}4]{k_0\cdot e^{-2\,\alpha\, R_\text{MAX}}}\\\\
R_\text{MAX}&=\sqrt[\leftroot{0}\uproot{2}4]{k_0}\cdot e^{-\frac12\,\alpha\, R_\text{MAX}}\\\\
R_\text{MAX}\cdot e^{\frac12\,\alpha\, R_\text{MAX}}&=\sqrt[\leftroot{0}\uproot{2}4]{k_0}\\\\
\frac12\,\alpha\,R_\text{MAX}\cdot e^{\frac12\,\alpha\, R_\text{MAX}}&=\frac12\,\alpha\,\sqrt[\leftroot{0}\uproot{2}4]{k_0}
\end{align*}$$

At this point, we just recall that if \$u\,e^u=v\$, then \$u=\operatorname{LambertW}\left(v\right)\$. So, we set \$u=\frac12\,\alpha\,R_\text{MAX}\$ and then:

$$\begin{align*}
\left(\frac12\,\alpha\,R_\text{MAX}\right)\, e^{^{\left(\frac12\,\alpha\,R_\text{MAX}\right)}}&=\frac12\,\alpha\,\sqrt[\leftroot{0}\uproot{2}4]{k_0}\\\\
u\, e^{u}&=\frac12\,\alpha\,\sqrt[\leftroot{0}\uproot{2}4]{k_0}\\\\
&\therefore\\\\
u&=\operatorname{LambertW}\left(\frac12\,\alpha\,\sqrt[\leftroot{0}\uproot{2}4]{k_0}\right)\\\\
\frac12\,\alpha\,R_\text{MAX}&=\operatorname{LambertW}\left(\frac12\,\alpha\,\sqrt[\leftroot{0}\uproot{2}4]{k_0}\right)\\\\
R_\text{MAX}&=\frac2{\alpha}\,\operatorname{LambertW}\left(\frac{\alpha}2\,\sqrt[\leftroot{0}\uproot{2}4]{k_0}\right)
\end{align*}$$

It's that simple. (Well, you get to hand-write out \$k_0\$ now. I don't want to have to write all that stuff, myself. But you know how to do that last step, I'm sure.)

Comment: Wow, this is a really detailed response. I appreciate your answer. I am going to look through it soon and try to understand it. I may take you up on that algebraic walk-through. As to why I am interested, I became curious about it and wanted to do a deeper dive on the subject and try to make a simple range calculation model.

Comment: @napoleon4269 Added the extra development for you.

Comment: That is some complex-looking stuff. Here is what I believe I understand. So if I have a number in decibels per km I would convert it into nepers by multiplying by 4.34 leading to: e^-2*4.34*alpha*Rmax.  I then solve for Rmax by using this Lambert equation because that variable is on both sides of the equation. This is going to sound like an odd question but how would I calculate the LambertW function for the variables you have in parenthesis? Is it just multiplying the variables in the parenthesis by u*e^u? Or am I just completely misunderstanding the LambertW?

Comment: @napoleon4269 Perhaps start with [Wolfram LambertW](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html). I wrote my own code because the function is missing from many math libraries. You can use a variety of numerical methods. The best to use would depend on your own skill sets, though. The [Wiki page on LambertW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) includes some approaches. But Toshio Fukushima's [Precise and fast computation of LambertW](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042712005213) from 2013 would also be a good source.

Comment: @napoleon4269 \$e^{-2\cdot \alpha\cdot R}\$ is a factor: a ratio of emitted vs received power. Decibels and nepers aren't factors. They are logarithmic scale values. Worse, decibels were originally units of power ratios, while nepers were (and are) defined as field ratios. The relationship between them has an inherent factor of 2 (because of the squared relationships between power and fields) as well as a factor difference based upon Log10(e). I converted a power factor to a logarithmic scale term to explain your text. But I fear you misunderstand the difference in meaning. (Or I'm mistaken.)

Comment: I am sorry if I am not being very clear. You can probably see now I do not have much knowledge in this. Let me explain what I do understand. I understand decibels and nepers are log scale values. I also understand e^-2*alpha*Rmax is the factor for attenuation. I have heard about the power/field thing but am still trying to understand it. Anyhow, what I was trying to say is if I have an alpha number as db/km, I could change it to nepers/km by multiplying by 4.34, because the formula calls for it to be in nepers. Is that sentence correct? Also, I found out a LambertW function on Python

Comment: @napoleon4269 Probably best to see: [Wiki on Nepers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neper). They discuss the conversion there.

Comment: So can you tell me if I was correct on the method for changing db/m to nepers/m? Also you have helped quite a bit. Clearly I am struggling with this part of the equation. I guess I need to sit down and try to figure out my issue.

Answer (score 0):

log₁₀(e) ×10=4.3429448190325176.

When used with dB/km this is the conversion factor.